# Creating quickstart maven project with different default class name

Tags: java, maven

Following Maven quickstart tutorial on http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html, I've got this project structure:
[image]

Is it possible to have my default class and test class being named like `MyApp.java` and `MyAppTest.java` instead of `App.java` and `AppTest.java` without having to manually rename them?

I am hoping for a one-liner command that would create me a project with that kind of structure and that would be slightly different than one they used:
`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`

Comment: Why do you need this? Do you plan creating many projects of this simple structure?

Comment: No, I am participating in a course that has several assignments that require us to create a project using this command, but after crating we would delete default names, and use classes with different names, I was just curious is it possible to create one with class names that I actually need without manually renaming, I googled it, but couldn't find the answer :( .

Comment: You still need to add some code to the file, so renaming it seems to be a relatively minor task compared to that. I guess you can write a small renaming script in bash if you really consider this task annoying?

Comment: Nah :) I will rename it myself, It was just a bit silly to me that maven has't got any support for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is impossible. 
Archetype is project template packed in .jar file.
In your case **maven-archetype-quickstart-1.1.jar**, can find it here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.1

If you look into jar, you'll see that project layout is saved in folder **maven-archetype-quickstart-1.1.jar/archetype-resources**.

You can also create your own archetype : http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/